# Show some text in a black background

Tags: python, opencv

Why if I introduce an image the text appears but if I "create" a background the text doesn't appear?

**Code with image:**

```
img = cv2.imread('img.png')
font, line, color = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, cv2.LINE_AA, (0,255,0)
cv2.putText(img, 'FILTERS', (100,100), font, 1, color, 1, line)
cv2.imshow('Filters',img)
```

**Code with background (not working):**

```
background = np.full((300,600), 0, dtype=np.uint8)
font, line, color = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, cv2.LINE_AA, (0,255,0)
cv2.putText(background, 'FILTERS', (100,100), font, 1, color, 1, line)
cv2.imshow('Filters',background)
```

I suppose because the second one isn't an image but I don't understand it because `imshow` shows it. A solution could be have a black image, but I prefer understanding why is happening this.

Comment: Might be tricky to draw an RGB text on a grayscale image. Try using `(300,600,3)` for the image dimensions. Also `background` vs `img` mismatch.

Comment: Perhaps because you are not writing the text onto the `background` image. Try cv2.putText(**background**, 'FILTERS', (100,100), font, 1, color, 1, line)

Comment: @fmw42 Sorry this was a mistake here, I just edit it.

Comment: @YannVernier Was this!! Write it in answers and I close the question! Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are placing colored text in a grayscale (shaped 300X600) background. To solve it, change background shape to 300X300X3:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

background = np.full((300,600,3), 0, dtype=np.uint8)
font, line, color = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, cv2.LINE_AA, (0,255,0)
cv2.putText(background, 'FILTERS', (100,100), font, 1, color, 1, line)
cv2.imshow('Filters',background)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```